# hreflang for two URLs with same language and different countries

Tags: internationalization, hreflang

Can we use `hreflang` like this:

```html
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.de/de/product/" hreflang="de-de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/de/product/" hreflang="de" />
```

Both pages are in German and same design, but the problem is we can only show the `.de` domain in Germany as per licence rules for our products, and `.com/de` domain rest of the countries for German language.

So I had the above set of `hreflang` but now I think Google may confuse because one side we are saying that in Germany show the `.de` but another side we are saying for all Germans show the `.com/de`.

What you suggest in this situation? We want both domains index in SERP.